# Keep Footer At Bottom Of Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I've got the following:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top">
    </div>

    <div class="left">
    </div>

    <div class="main">
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.top {                                                                          
    position: absolute;                                                         
    left: 0;                                                                    
    height: 80px;                                                               
    width: 100%;                                                                
} 


.left {                                                                         
    position: absolute;                                                         
    left: 0; top: 80px; bottom: 100px;                                          
    width: 200px;                                                               
    margin-left: 5px;                                                           
}

.main {                                                                         
    position: absolute;                                                         
    left: 200px; top: 80px; bottom: 100px;                                      
    width: 84%;                                                                                                                     
}   

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I'd like to keep the `footer` at the bottom of the page (after `left` and `main`, and regardless of how big/small `main` is), but with `position: fixed` the footer scrolls up/down as you scroll through the page. I've tried `position: absolute` and that doesn't push the footer all the way to the bottom. I've tried some of the other solutions found here and none have worked. How can I keep the footer at the bottom of the page (similar to the `footer` at the bottom of this page)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/xwjhn7ej/7/ ? ... Less content than viewport footer at bottom window - more content than viewport footer at bottom of container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.footer{
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0
}
```

Position absolute moves footer according to the element that contains it. Bottom 0 keeps the footer at the bottom of it's parent.

This will work if the parent of the absolute positioned element has relarive position. To say it more particular, your `wrapper` needs to have the following code:

```
.wrapper{
   position: relative
}
```

Comment: This should work, but I've just noticed that both `body` and `wrapper` have a height of 0px, `left` has a height of 214px, and `main` has a height of 64px despite containing content that has a height of > 2000px. Something wonky going on for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed does what you're describing, locks elements with your viewport. Absolute makes an element ignore the flow of the rest of your page, so if you want to make it go beneath everything else you'll run into problems. Give this a shot, it'll put it underneath all your content.

```
footer{
  position: relative
  width: 100%
  float: left
}
```

If you need it to stay at the very bottom of the screen when you have very short content, you can add a wrapper element around everything and try something like this

```
.wrapper{
  display: block;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: footer height (set this to how tall your footer is)
}
footer{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
    .left {                                                                         
float:left;                                          
width: 200px;                                                               
margin-left: 5px;                                                           
}
#right {
   float:left;
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

And for older browsers:

```
#container {
   height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use position for every `<div>` you only need to add position to .footer

[Here is a working example...](http://codepen.io/apmeena/pen/JKAdkJ)